# What can i use as a ComboBox alternative for Windows Phone development? (vb)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I've been thoroughly looking for a combobox alternative to use for Windows Phone development for a full 24 hours now. The best i've found so far was [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx)
,which is perfectly fine, but i'm really looking for something to work with in Vb.net.

PS: I'm using Visual studio 2010 as my code editor

Anticipated thanks :)

Comment: Telerik has a ListPicker. http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The List Picker is the best alternative to a ComboBox. 
You can get the List Picker by installing the Toolkit update: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034

It doesn't matter whether you use VB or C#. The Listpicker is basically a control in XAML, in the design view. 
The only difference would be the Databinding syntax in your code view.